# group by error : this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

i have two tables order and order_detail

```
order
id   |  total   |  date
------------------------
 1      3500      2018-02-10
 2      1000      2018-02-18

order_detail
id  |  order_id  |  item_id  |  quantity
-------------------------------------------------
 1          1            4         20
 2          1            6         10
 3          2            3         50
```

i am trying to achive

```
orderCount  |  itemCount  | totalAmount  
----------------------------------------
  2               80            4500
```

i have written this query for extracting last 30day summary:

```
select COUNT(*) as orderCount  
     , (select SUM(od.quantity) 
          from order_detail od 
         where od.order_id = o.id

       ) as itemCount
     , SUM(o.total) as totalSum 
  from order o 
 WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= o.date
```

this query works fine  in local mysql database

but in production server it is generating following error:

```
#1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'databaseb.o.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: Your production server is set up correctly. Your local database is not. For assistance with the construction of a valid query, see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: And when you googled the error message without your specific stings & googled sql_mode only_full_group_by you learned ...? (Hint: No, your query was not "fine".) Also--What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd column:

```
 (select SUM(od.quantity) 
      from order_detail od 
     where od.order_id = o.id
   ) as itemCount
```

Is *not* an aggregated value; it's the result of a subquery (which happens to produce aggregated value, but that is irrelevant).

You must add:

```
group by 2
```

To your query to conform with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`.

Obviously your local database does not have `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` set.

---

I suspect you just want a join:

```
select COUNT(*) as orderCount  
  , SUM(od.quantity) as itemCount
  , SUM(o.total) as totalSum 
from order o 
left join order_detail od on od.order_id = o.id
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= o.date
```

Comment: adding group by 2  makes the query executable but it doen't achieve the desired result. i am bit stuck

Comment: @user9305153 see edited answer for a join solution that will probably work for you

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your desire output  you can simple use below query

```
select sum(od.quantity) as itemCount,
sum(o.total) as totalAmount,
count(distinct(o.id)) as orderCount
from order_detail od
left join `order` o 
on od.id=o.id ;
```